# JS can't call a function

Tags: javascript, function, call

Small problem here, I can't call a function ^^

Here's what's at the bottom of my page (just to test):

```
function test() 
{
    alert();
}

test();
```

The `alert()` function just won't be called. I'll post more details if needed to find out what's wrong.

Comment: working fine at http://jsfiddle.net/v4bEJ/1/

Comment: its work perfectly with an alert `undefined`

Comment: Check your browser settings. Browsers have the ability to stop alert dialogs from being openned. Especially when your testing and loading that page a lot. Chrome I believe can "learn" this without prompting the user as well.

Comment: you may have disabled alert when previously shown, 
if your browser is chrome, restart browser and check.

Comment: Alerts aren't disabled, 

When i write alert(); right below test();, it works fine, it's not a problem due to disabling alerts

I have other commands in that function actually, the alert(); is just to check whether it enters the function or not...

Does the fact that there is some JS loaded at the beginning (with script src=test.js) have anything to do ?

Answer (score 3):

Give an argument to your alert function.
Be sure you didn't have disable alert windows for this page (in this case, close and open the page again).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, you're just not alerting anything.

```
function test(val) {
    alert(val);
}
test("What ever you want to alert!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might declare the typ of script by adding `type="text/javascript"` to your script tag. I tried your code it works for me in Chrome and Firefox even without the declaration.

Also in JSFiddl it works : http://jsfiddle.net/jH9ad/

It shows an empty dialog.